# Sometimes Code Runs and Sometimes it gives error

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

Below is my code to scrape a site using beautiful soup..The code runs fine on windows but has issues on ubuntu. In ubuntu, the code sometimes run and sometimes give error.

**The error is below:**

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "Craftsvilla.py", line 22, in <module>
    source =  requests.get(new_url)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/requests/api.py", line 70, in get
    return request('get', url, params=params, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/requests/api.py", line 56, in request
    return session.request(method=method, url=url, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/requests/sessions.py", line 488, in request
    resp = self.send(prep, **send_kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/requests/sessions.py", line 609, in send
    r = adapter.send(request, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/requests/adapters.py", line 487, in send
    raise ConnectionError(e, request=request)
requests.exceptions.ConnectionError: HTTPConnectionPool(host='www.craftsvilla.com', port=80): Max retries exceeded with url: /shop/01-princess-ayesha-cotton-salwar-suit-for-rudra-house/5601472 (Caused by NewConnectionError('<requests.packages.urllib3.connection.HTTPConnection object at 0x7f6685fc3310>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno -2] Name or service not known',))
```

**Below is my code:**

```
import requests
import lxml
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import xlrd
import xlwt

file_location = "/home/nitink/Python Linux/BeautifulSoup/Craftsvilla/Craftsvilla.xlsx"

workbook = xlrd.open_workbook(file_location)

sheet = workbook.sheet_by_index(0)

products = []
for r in range(sheet.nrows):
    products.append(sheet.cell_value(r,0))

book = xlwt.Workbook(encoding= "utf-8", style_compression = 0)
sheet = book.add_sheet("Sheet11", cell_overwrite_ok=True)

for index, url in enumerate(products):
    new_url = "http://www." + url
    source =  requests.get(new_url)
    data = source.content
    soup = BeautifulSoup(data, "lxml")

    sheet.write(index, 0, url)

    try:
        Product_Name = soup.select(".product-title")[0].text.strip()
        sheet.write(index, 1, Product_Name)

    except Exception:
        sheet.write(index, 1, "")

book.save("Craftsvilla Output.xls")
```

Save the below links as Craftsvilla.xlsx

```
craftsvilla.com/shop/01-princess-ayesha-cotton-salwar-suit-for-rudra-house/5601472
craftsvilla.com/shop/3031-pista-prachi/3715170
craftsvilla.com/shop/795-peach-colored-stright-salwar-suit/5608295
craftsvilla.com/catalog/product/view/id/5083511/s/dharm-fashion-villa-embroidery-navy-blue-slawar-suit-gown
```

**Note:** For some guys the code will run, but try for sometime..the same code would give error..dont know why??..and the same code will never give any error on windows.

Comment: I think you're sending too many requests from same IP address in short period of time, So the server may refuse your connection.

Comment: but why the same code never give error on windows.

Comment: add `print(new_url)` after `new_url`, I think you read the xlsx file and get the incomplete data.

Comment: ```pip install pyopenssl```. Sometimes its just about an ssl error, where oyur requests line keeps retrying and failing.

Answer (score 2):

It looks like you are *hitting the site too often* and the server rejects your requests. Be a [good web-scraping citizen](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/91760/how-to-be-a-good-citizen-when-crawling-web-sites) and add a time delay between the consequent requests:

```
import time

for index, url in enumerate(products):
    new_url = "http://www." + url
    source =  requests.get(new_url)
    data = source.content
    soup = BeautifulSoup(data, "lxml")

    # ...

    time.sleep(1)  # one second delay
```